# How to mock a call of an inner method from a Junit

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have MyClass and I am doing a test-class for every method (Method1Test)

```
public class MyClass {
    public int method1(){
        int a = method2();
        return a;
    }
    public int method2(){
        return 0;
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Method1Test {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    @Before
    public void setup(){}
    @Test
    public void test01(){
        Mockito.when(myClass.method2()).thenReturn(25);
        int a = myClass.method1();
        assertTrue("We did it!!!",a==25);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to mock the call to method2 to make it return a diferent value. The Mockito sentence don't do the work.

Very thanks ^_^

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a spy on the class-under-test and partially mock it by redefining the behavior for the `method2()` of the spy

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


public class Method1Test {

  private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

  @Test
  public void test01(){
    //given
    MyClass spy = spy(myClass); //create a spy for class-under-test
    when(spy.method2()).thenReturn(25); //partially override behavior of the spy
    //when
    int a = spy.method1(); //make the call to method1 of the _spy_!
    //then
    assertEquals(25, a);
  }
}
```

Apart from this, you don't require neither the Mockito Runner nor the `@InjectMocks` for your test as you're doing no injection of `@Mock` annotated mocks into the class-under-test.

Further, the message in the `assertTrue` statement is only displayed, when the condition of the assertion is *NOT* fulfilled. So it should be *at least* "We failed!!!" ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I find a transversal solution without create a new class (I haven't been able to do it because it is forbbiden in the actual project). I have overwrited the method in the test.

The solution is

```
public class MyClass {
    public int method1(){
        int a=0;
        a=method2();
        return a;
    }
    public int method2(){
        return 1;
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Method1Test {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass = new MyClass(){
        public int method2(){
            return 25;
        }
    };
    @Before
    public void setup(){}
    @Test
    public void test001(){
        Mockito.when(myClass.method2()).thenReturn(25);
        int a = myClass.method1();
        assertTrue("We did it!!!",a==25);
    }
}
```

Comment: technically speaking, you _are_ creating a new class, though it's an anonymous one. But what you are doing now is same as writing mocks on your own as it was done in the pre-mockito era. Use a spy instead.

Comment: So, In my opinion, I disagree with your solution because you only override the method in your test. Can you imagine testing different methods and overriden every one? It is awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution using the code below, but It didn't pass.

```
Mockito.when(myClass.method2()).thenReturn(25);
```

Afterwards, Instead of the code snippet above, I tried something different and the test passed successfully. Take a look:

```
Mockito.doReturn(25).when(myClass).method2();
```

In order to mock a test (It might be a inner method), you have to use doReturn() method.

> You can use doThrow(), doAnswer(), doNothing(), doReturn() and doCallRealMethod() in place of the corresponding call with when(), for any method. It is necessary when you
>
> - stub void methods
> - stub methods on spy objects (see below)
> - stub the same method more than once, to change the behaviour of a mock in the middle of a test.
>
> but you may prefer to use these methods in place of the alternative
>   with when(), for all of your stubbing calls.

Furthermore information can be read here https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mock(class) here we need to use Mockito.spy() to mock the same class we are testing. Then we can mock the method we want as follows.

```
@Test

  public void method1Test() { 

  MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

  MyClass myClass1 = Mockito.spy(myClass);

  Mockito.doReturn(1).when(myClass1).method2();

  Assert.assertEquals(1, myClass1.method1());

     }
 }
```