# How to mock a class in another class junit mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Following are the 2 classes defined as:

```
Class1{
   public method1
    {
        class2.getInstance().method2();
    }
}

Class2{
   public static getInstance() { .... }

   public method2() { .... }

   public Class3 obj = new Class3();
}
```

I need to write junit test for method1 of class1.
But I need to know how can I mock getInstance() and method2() of class2.

Also, please tell me how can I mock object of Class3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object

Answer (score 1):

If you find it hard to write a good test for your class, you should redesign your class for better testability, that's the reason TDD is also called *Test Driven **Design***. It should never be difficult to write a test for a simple class.

However,

- how to mock static methods is described here [PowerMockito mock single static method and return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object) (thanks to Jorge)
- how to partially mock a class is already described here: 
  [How to mock a call of an inner method from a Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095096/how-to-mock-a-call-of-an-inner-method-from-a-junit/)

Answer (score 0):

For this task (e.g. mocking `new`) you need another framework. For example [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock).

Comment: If possible, can you please help me out with an example ?

Comment: Look at Geralds answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

So man, guys which already answered you  are right.

> If you find it hard to write a good test for your class, you should redesign your class for better testability, that's the reason TDD is also called Test Driven Design. It should never be difficult to write a test for a simple class.
>
> However,
>
> how to mock static methods is described here PowerMockito mock single static method and return object (thanks to Jorge)
>   how to partially mock a class is already described here: How to mock a call of an inner method from a Junit

I can add following:

If you really have good reasons to do what you want I advice you further:

You can use [Whitebox.setInternalState()](https://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.4.10/apidocs/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html#setInternalState(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method of powermock library in order to mock object of Class3.

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(class2, "obj", class3Mock);
```