# Using PowerMockito to mock object creation

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

Can anyone give an idea of how to mock object creation for `A a= new B()` using PowerMockito (Class B implements the interface A)?
I have tried as follows. But the mock object is not used in the class under the test but a new object is created under that class.

```
B b=Mockito.spy(B.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn((b));
```

Comment: Don't, don't, don't, don't, don't. Entire frameworks exist _specifically to prevent you from doing this_. In 98% of cases, pass `b` as a constructor parameter; in the remaining 2%, pass a `Supplier<B>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way with `PowerMockito`

```
B b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(b);
```

A working `PowerMockito` example is given in this answer
[JUnit: mock a method called inside another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199598/junit-mock-a-method-called-inside-another-method/65200268#65200268)